# How to build a GUI for linux? from Scratch

Tags: linux, user-interface, operating-system, desktop, window-managers

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptcHHXp1PEU) and now I want to learn how to build my own window manager and GUI desktop but I have many questions
 1. How do i capture the events(click, resize) and notify the process?
 2. How do I notify the process the window resolution?
 3. How do I get the rendered images so that I can forward them to my process?
 4. How does the process workflow look like?
 5. Which references or books might help?

I am interested in the process and languages or commands needed not on how to install and run Xserver or similar solutions because I want to make my own.
Id like to start from a command line based linux distro.(Is this possible)

Comment: Hi, have you found any reliable information on this?

Comment: Have you seen this thread "https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/214nd9/making_a_gui_from_scratch/"? Might have some useful tips about creating a graphics server (which I just learned is a term for what I think you're trying to create - an X alternative). Slabity and AnarchyLime give some overview, Zotoaster has more details.

Comment: how does linux's window system work: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596894/how-does-linuxs-display-work

Comment: x11 window creation (perhaps a starting point for reverse engineering) https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Window_creation/X11#AArch64_Assembly

Answer (score -2):

I would use Java. It is widely used and has suited me well.